# How to do Github auto commit?

Tags: python, git, github, automation, commit

I have a Python script (located on my desktop PC) that launches itself and does some calculation on a daily basis and outputs a txt file in the same folder. I want to figure out a way to auto commit this output file into my github repo (to be viewed on my phone on the go). The reason for this is I don't want to run the python script on my phone but I want to be able to view the script output when I don't have access to the desktop.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Just use `popen` and run `git commit -m ... theFile.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-file-contents

You should be able to spin up a bash script to do this at a certain time every day pretty easily. This is a quick example, the command was taken from the docs.
If you aren't on linux, then you could definitely do it in powershell just as easily. I wouldn't copy and paste this, because I probably made a mistake this is just what it would look like. It could be done in Python as well.

````
#!/bin/bash

folder="/path/to/file/"  
file="file.txt"

commit() {
    cd "$folder" || exit 1
    git add "$file"
    git commit -m "Auto-commit"
    commit_sha=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
    commit_id=$(git log --format="%H" -n 1)
    echo "File committed at $(date)"
    echo "Commit SHA: $commit_sha"
    echo "Commit ID: $commit_id"
}

current_time=$(date +"%H:%M")

if [[ $current_time == "?desired time?" ]]; then
    commit
else
    echo "No commit scheduled for today."

curl -L \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/contents/PATH \
  -d '{"message":"a new commit message","committer":{"name":"Monalisa Octocat","email":"octocat@github.com"},"content":"$commit_id","sha":"$commit_sha"}'```


fi
````